# How to get information from an image?

Tags: android, image

I try to get image details to my application, like **date taken, camera model, width, height, description....**  any one help me how can I do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ExifInterface` you can get attributes of the captured image if your camera was configured to write them.
For more details see a link.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Answer (score 2):

Look into ExifInterface http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called EXIF.  I'm not an Android dev but this looks like a good starting point: http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/reading-exif-information-from-a-picture-file-in-android